# React: Drag and Drop files makes uploaded file non-interactive

Tags: css, reactjs, file-upload

So I am trying to develop a drag and drop feature where each uploaded file can be removed later.

This is the layout when no file is uploaded.

[image]

Below layout results when multiples files have been uploaded.
[image]

As you can see there is a bin icon. I'm expecting to click this icon to remove the uploaded file. I have implemented the functionality but because of Drag and drop "input" I can select the delete icon. It just opens the upload file window which I suppose is superseeding the cards.

I can get the delete functionality to work by setting display:none in my UploadFile but then I loose the drag and drop functionality. Can someone suggest a way around this scenario? I want to keep drag and drop feature but also want to delete the file if required.

Here is my styled input implementing the drag and drop feature:

```
const UploadFile = styled("input")`
  font-size: 18px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-transform: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  &:focus {
    outline: none;
  }
`;
```

The second issue is that I want to fix the boundary of the parent card so that when a new file is uploaded it should adjust inside the available space and not expand the entire component as it is doing currently.

Here is the code for this entire component:

```
return (
    <>
      <FileUploadContainer>
        <InputLabel>{props.label}</InputLabel>
        {fileUrlList.length > 0 ? (
          <UploadLabel onClick={uploadSelectedFiles}>Upload</UploadLabel>
        ) : (
          ""
        )}
        <Container>
          <DragDropText>
            Drag and drop single or multiple files such as sketch , reference
            imgs trim, fabric, etc.
          </DragDropText>
          {fileUrlList.length > 0 ? (
            ""
          ) : (
            <PrimaryButton onClick={onFileUploadClick}>Upload</PrimaryButton>
          )}

          <UploadFile
            type="file"
            ref={fileInputField}
            onChange={onFileUpload}
            title=""
            value=""
          />
          <UploadedFilesContainer>
            {fileUrlList.map((item) => (
              <FileRow key={item.name} className={"row"}>
                <div className={"col-11"}>
                  <a href={item.url} target={"_blank"}>
                    {item.name}
                  </a>
                </div>
              </FileRow>
            ))}
          </UploadedFilesContainer>
        </Container>
      </FileUploadContainer>
    </>
  );
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!